# VBA- global object failed even though range exists

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write up a script which will do the following things in the following order:

1. Locate a range that is located between 2 cells containing specific strings (DateRng)
2. Search within this range for a cell (i) that has a value <=Value
3. Compare two other cells which are offset to "i"
4. Export a range of rows centered around "i" to different sheets pending the outcome of 
   the above condition.

I can get steps 2 & 4 to work (if step 2 searched the entire sheet instead of DateRng.
I can also get step 1 to work

However, when I try to put it all together I get an error msg: Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed.

This makes no sense to me as DateRng is being found. 
If someone could advise on this that would be great. I have just started learning VBA so i am wide open to suggestions/corrections for the rest of the script too.

Below I have pasted the offending script with the line the Debugger stops on **marked**

```
Sub ReportCells()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Dim j, k As Long
Dim StartDate, FinishDate As String
Dim Sh As Worksheet: Set Sh = Sheets("Full chart and primary cals")
Dim CellFound As Range

'Range Extraction Script
'Search location and values
LookupColumn = "B"
StartDate = "2013.01.02 20:00"
FinishDate = "2013.01.09 20:00"
'Find Lower Limit
For j = 1 To 30000
If Sh.Range(LookupColumn & j).Value = FinishDate Then FinishDateRow = j
Next j
'Find Upper Limit
For k = FinishDateRow To 1 Step -1
If Sh.Range(LookupColumn & k).Value = StartDate Then StartDateRow = k - 1
Next k
'Set Range once located
Dim DateRng As Range: Set DateRng = Sh.Range(LookupColumn & StartDateRow & ":" & LookupColumn & FinishDateRow)

MsgBox DateRng.Address

'Find Cell
**With Range("DateRng")**
For i = 1 To LR
Set CellFound = .Find(Sh.Range("M:M").Value <= 25)
If Not CellFound Is Nothing And .Range("CellFound").Offset(0, -4).Value < .Range("CellFound").Offset(-10, -4).Value Then .Offset(-3, 0).Resize(10, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet18").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
If Not CellFound Is Nothing And .Range("CellFound").Offset(0, -4).Value > .Range("CellFound").Offset(-10, -4).Value Then .Offset(-3, 0).Resize(10, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet19").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Edit: So the suggested fix corrected the error, however now I am experiencing what i guess is an error in the logic. The script is not returning any cells to sheet18 or sheet19.
I know there should be cells returned as these cells are able to be found if looked for manually. there are no error messages and the script appears to run normally. I have stripped back the code under the previously offending script and cannot seem to locate where  the error in the logic is. Maybe it has something to do with this line(?):

```
 Set CellFound = .Find(Sh.Range("M:M").Value <= 25)
```

Comment: Did you mean to use a named range (`"DateRng"`) or did you mean to use the variable `DateRng` ? There is a big difference there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely you have used `Range("DateRng")` -- a named range -- instead of `DateRng` which is really the range you have defined on the line just above, by mistake.

I suggest trying the following:

```
With DateRng
    '...
End With
```

Edit:

The code following that line tells me this is definitely a mistake you have made. When you define a range object you have to use it as is. You cannot call it by passing a string with the variable name to a call to `Range()` (see `"CellFound"` for the other mistake).

Comment: Thank you Alexandre. That was exactly it.
So, just to be sure I understand, once a range is set it is called by RangeName not "RangeName". If an unnamed range if called it is called as "cellref:cellref"?

Comment: Exactly. Only if you want to use a named range you can use the `Range("named_range")` syntax.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that for me. I know a little Java and some R but learning VBA has been one hell of a rollercoaster.
Are you able to shed any light on the new issue that has arisen? Should I start a new thread?